# Function returns "empty" response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem how to properly call/return one function data. I have this function displayTableWithCountryStates which is calling getCountryStates function. The problem is that when i make request $.get i get proper response, but when i try to return this response, console.log(countryStates) inside displayTableWithCountryStates is empty

```
countryStatesTables = {

    displayTableWithCountryStates: function (source, newForm) {
        var countryId = 237;
        var countryStates = countryStatesTables.getCountryStates(countryId);
        console.log(countryStates); // Response is empty
    },

    getCountryStates: function (countryId) {
        if (countryId !== '' || countryId !== 'undefined') {
            $.get(balthazar.settings.logistics.getCountryStatesUrl.url + '/' + countryId, function (data) {
                console.log(data.data); //Response is ok, data is present
                return data.data;
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Why and how to properly return data in my displayTableWithCountryStates function. If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Comment: Look in the console at the *order* your two console.logs are shown, the empty one is first because the `$.get` is asynchronous - ie hasn't finished yet.  See link for more details.

Comment: may be you should use keyword `this` :   var countryStates = this.getCountryStates(countryId);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronous functions need callbacks to handle the data as we don't know exactly when they would return the output. You can also it with promises.

```js
countryStatesTables = {

    displayTableWithCountryStates: function (source, newForm) {
        var countryId = 237;
        var countryStates = this.getCountryStates(countryId, function(data){
          console.log(countryStates);
        });
    },

    getCountryStates: function (countryId, callback) {
        if (countryId !== '' || countryId !== 'undefined') {
            $.get(balthazar.settings.logistics.getCountryStatesUrl.url + '/' + countryId, function (data) {
                console.log(data.data); //Response is ok, data is present
                callback(data.data);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: We dont' need ***yet another*** answer to this question.

Comment: I realize that fact perfectly well, but I felt that if the person has asked this question he is a newbie to async function calls and probably to javascript, so I answered anyway. Marking the question as duplicate could be the right thing to do but I understand the place this guy is in so hell with that strict attitude !

Comment: Exactly! Thank you @SourabReddy